# How to preserve session data in cross-origin requests?

Tags: node.js, express, session, cors, node.js-connect

I'm new to using Express and Connect, so I'm hoping I'm doing something stupid that has a simple solution.

Basically, I have a page where a user logs in using Persona. To validate authentication attempts, I use [express-persona](https://npmjs.org/package/express-persona). Supposedly, this module saves the user's validated email address in a session variable (req.session.email, by default).

Now, after logging in, users can post a comment, and this comment will be saved together with the email address with which the user logged in. When the server that serves the form is the same as the one that handles the posting of the comment, this works fine. However, when they are different (let's say the user fills in the form at `http://localhost:8001`, whereas the browser then sends a POST request to `http://localhost:8000` which should save the comment), all of a sudden the req.session.email value is `undefined`.

I *think* I set up Cross-Origin Resource Sharing correctly. The form is sent thusly (using jQuery):

```
$.ajax('http://localhost:8000/post/comment',
       {
           data: {comment: $('#commentField').val()},
           type: 'POST',
           xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}
       }
);
```

(Note the `xhrField: {withCredentials: true}` -- the session cookie is passed along, which I verified by inspecting the network request.)

The server sets up the (I think) correct CORS headers:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8001');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
```

When I add `console.log(req.cookie)`, I see the `sessionId` cookie that has the same value as the one sent along with the POST request.

*However:* `console.log(req.session.email)` displays `undefined` for cross-origin requests -- again, it works fine when the requests come from the same origin.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you putting your console.log statements? What does your Express .use() statements look like? Are you running the console.log before the express-pesona middleware has a chance to run and update the session information?

Comment: The console.log()s are in the Express application and are called after use()ing Persona and the comment processing module -- when the requests are from the same origin, they output the correct values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out my problem: I forgot to send cookies with the authentication request. Hence, the Express server could not identify the current user's session when logging in, and consequently could not save the user data to the session.

The solution was to also send the Persona assertion request with the `withCredentials` flag, as such:

```
var response = $.ajax(assertionUrl + '/verify', {
    data: {assertion: assertion},
    type: 'POST',
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}
});
```

(I don't think anyone will ever run into this exact same problem, but just in case...)

Answer (score 3):

For those who are looking to solve the same problem with Angular implementations. You can configure $http to send cookies using:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    //rest of route code
```

Comment: I can't find the original link anymore. I've remove it from my post